# unable to add window token null is not for an application when using accessibility in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-dialog

I am trying to create a transparent activity in front of another app's login page. `MyAccessibilityService` Class extend the `AccessibilityService` class. When login page is identified the `tranparentActivity()` function will be called to show the dialog box, but I will get the error like `unable to add window token null is not for an application when using accessibility in android`.

My Code:

```
      public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
       public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
{
    try{
    AccessibilityNodeInfo focusedNodeSrc = event.getSource();
    AccessibilityNodeInfo childNode;
    if(focusedNodeSrc.isPassword()){
        transparentActivity();
    }
    else{
        AccessibilityNodeInfo parFocusedNode=focusedNodeSrc.getParent();
        int countChild = parFocusedNode.getChildCount();
        for(int i=0;i<countChild;i++){
            childNode = parFocusedNode.getChild(i);
            if(childNode.isPassword()){
                transparentActivity();
            }}}}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(MyAccessibilityService.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
public void transparentActivity(){
    // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                dialog.setTitle("Title...");
                // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
                ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();}});
                dialog.show();}
```

I searched in google about this error and from this I understand it is a context problem. The given solution from google is not applicable in my case I think. So please can anyone post any suggestions on how to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getApplicationContext()`, but after that line, you should add this flag of WindowManager:

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

and the error will not show